# Error en peticion GET de Vue CLI a Asp.Net core Web Api

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

estoy obteniendo este error en la consola del navegador cuando intento llamar una accion de un controlador de Asp.net core webApi desde una aplicacion de vue cli, es algo pequeño que solo requiere una tabla en base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo quiero hacer es una peticion con la herramienta axios y imprimir la respuesta por consola

Ya instale el plugin de Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors, agregue las cors al archivo startup.cs

Aqui esta el resto del codigo:
startup.cs

```cs
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextManager>(options =>

            options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Conexion")));

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Todos",

                builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").WithHeaders("*").WithMethods("*"));
            });

        }
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            else
            {      
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("Todos");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

controlador ejemplo

```cs
  // GET: api/Accounts        
     [HttpGet("[action]")]
     public async Task<IEnumerable<AccountViewModel>> Listar()
     {
            var accounts = await _context.Accounts.ToListAsync();

            return accounts.Select(a => new AccountViewModel
            {
                IdAccount = a.IdAccount,
                WebAccountName = a.WebAccountName,
                UserAccount = a.UserAccount,
                Password = a.Password,
                Description = a.Description,
                Email = a.Email
            });
      }
```

Este es el metodo vue con la peticion

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                accounts:[],  
                id: ''                                                                                                             
            }
        },          
        created () {
         this.listar();
        },
        methods:{
          listar(){
            let me=this;
              axios.get('http://localhost:44364/api/Accounts/listar')
                .then(function(response){
                    console.log(response);                    
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }                              
        }        
    }
</script>
```

Que podria hacer para solucionar el error?
gracias de antemano

Comment: Primero lo primero, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta colocando código en lugar de puras imágenes, haces más fácil el proceso de debugging para los usuarios que deseen resolver tu pregunta. Por otro lado ve a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y obtengas de paso tu primera medalla. También revisa cómo preguntar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask recuerda que a mayor calidad en preguntas, mayor calidad en respuestas :D

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias, ya llevo tiempo aca solo que ha cambiado mucho pero ya mismo arreglo la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En la consola dice:

```
http://localhost:44364
```

en tu código hay:

```
http://localhost:56686
```

Por lo tanto, en el perfil json de tu proyecto determina un puerto fijo como el clásico 5000 y las consultas las realizas del mismo modo.

Dato adicional que puede ser de utilidad:

Tengo un ejemplo de VueJS (con vue-resource en lugar de Axios) + ASPnet Core + EF Core + PostgreSQL en [mi blog](http://fredyfx.com/post/elevando-el-cosmos-con-aspnetcore-2-vuejs-entity-framework-core-2-y-postgresql-parte-5/)

Comment: Estoy apenado hermano fue un error de mi parte colocando la pregunta, pero el error es el mismo, el numero del puerto es tal cual el mismo de que me genera el servidor de visual studio, de todas formas voy a revisar tu ejemplo, gracias por tu respuesta